# Slim Framework - how to output arrays without templates?

Tags: php, slim, php-7

How can I write array outputs in Slim?

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $array = ['message' => 'Hello World'];
    $response->getBody()->write($array);
    return $response;
});
```

Error:

> Slim Application Error The application could not run because of the
>   following error:
>
> Details
>
> Type: RuntimeException Message: Could not write to stream File:
>   /var/www/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Http/Stream.php Line: 407

I just want to output arrays to the screen without any templates, nor json. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you cannot `echo` an array you need to form a string which then can be written to the outputstream.

```
$response->getBody()->write(print_r($array, true));
```

The second parameter of [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is that it should return the value and not print it directly.

The PHPDoc specifies that the write method only accept a string see [`\Slim\Http\Response`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Http/Response.php#L256)